# How do I prevent it from newlining in html?

Tags: html, css, inline

I have the following code in html, which creates this:

[image]

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb5" class="listDropDown" onchange="selectPopulationChanged()" display="inline" value="complex ab. karyotype">
<label for="cb5" class="listDropDown" display="inline">complex ab. karyotype</label>
```

Int his example, because of the spaces in "complex ab. karyotype", it decides to move all the text from the label tag below the checkmark.

How can I prevent it from doing so. My pop-up on the picture consists of code I posted, which is used several times to create a list. The only different between this particular element compared with the others (except for the length) is the spaces. I have tested by including an elemtn that is very long without spaces, and it doesn't throw it on a new line.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

***EDIT - ADDED the following***

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="display:inline">
    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="pops" >Select Populations</button>
    <ul id="popupDropDown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
```

jQuery:

```
function addCheckboxes() {
    $("#popupDropDown").empty();
    for(i=0; i<arrayValues.length; i++)
    {
        var container = $('#popupDropDown');
        var inputs = container.find('input');
        var id = inputs.length+1;
        $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', 'id': 'cb'+id, 'class': 'listDropDown', 'onChange': 'selectPopulationChanged()', 'display':'inline', value: arrayValues[i] }).appendTo(container);
        $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, 'class': 'listDropDown', 'display':'inline', text: arrayValues[i] }).appendTo(container);
        $('</br>').appendTo(container);
        $('#cb'+id).prop('checked', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `<label><input type="checkbox" /> Text</label>` would probably help.

Comment: Many options; lower font-size, more width(on parent) or more padding(on parent).

Comment: or put a limit on the width and use ellipsis http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Whilst that's a semantic option, I think it's detrimental to accessibility to wrap the input in label, even-though it seems intuitive to do so.

Comment: You can also define a width for the label and display it with inline-block . http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/xjtq4/7/

Comment: Post your HTML/CSS please.

Comment: I found where i read about the accessibility issue and it's pertaining  to IE6 and how implicit association does not make labels clickable. IE6 accessibility, in my opinion, is a non-issue. So i retract my previous caveat about implicit associations with labels.

Comment: The width of the pop-up is automatically expanded if the text is long enough, it works when there are no spaces in the text. @NiettheDarkAbsol This solution would work, but I am creating the HTML using jQuery, and I can't figure out how to include input inside of the label. This is the code I use for creating my HTML (the reason is that it needs to be dynamic): http://puu.sh/8SB0B.txt

Comment: @Vanquiza I have answered with some plain JavaScript code to do it for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in your `for` loop (replace all existing contents of said loop):

```
var container = document.getElementById('popupDropDown');
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.className = "listDropDown";

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = "checkbox";
input.className = "listDropDown";
input.onchange = selectPopulationChanged;
input.value = arrayValues[i];

label.appendChild(input);
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrayValues[i]));

container.appendChild(label);
```

This will put the checkbox *inside* the `<label>`, as I mentioned in my comment, and with that done you should be able to use `white-space:nowrap` on your label elements to prevent the line wrapping. Also, add `display:block` to the labels to avoid the need for `<br />` tags.

[Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) may take more writing, but personally I find this much easier to read than your very large jQuery generation stuff.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is so simple and helped me out a great deal! Praise The Dark Absol!

Answer (score 0):

@Nit the Dark Absol is already giving a hint.

```
<label class="listDropDown" style="white-space: nowrap">
<input type="checkbox" id="cb5" class="listDropDown" onchange="selectPopulationChanged()" value="complex ab. karyotype">complex ab. karyotype
</label>
```

Notice that the 'for'-attribute is gone and the nowrap property is applied.

To apply this in your jQuery code, append your input to your label and use the CSS property for your label.

```
var mylabel = $('<label />', {
    'for' : 'cb' + id,
    'class' : 'listDropDown',
    text : arrayValues[i],
    css : {
        'display' : 'inline',
        'white-space' : 'no-wrap'
    }
}).appendTo(container);

var myinput = $('<input />', {
    type : 'checkbox',
    'id' : 'cb' + id,
    'class' : 'listDropDown',
    'onChange' : 'selectPopulationChanged()',
    css : {
        'display' : 'inline'
    },
    value : arrayValues[i]
}).appendTo(mylabel);
```

i am also not so sure if that display property will be applied teh way you have it, but you can place that in the css property as shown.

Comment: Thank, I understand Dark Absols hint and it does indeed work, which is great! But as I mentioned I am creating this using jQuery as editted on my question. I am trying to do the following with jQuery, but am having trouble placing input inside of label AND including the css `style="white-space: nowrap"`